# looking for resources to learn MusixTeX (and how to setup on latex)

Tags: software, sheet-music

I'm was browsing through the web to look for possible softwares to write **beautiful** music sheets. I came across MusicTeX and I think this is what I need. But somehow there aren't many documentation that explains how it is done.

I already have experience with LaTeX, but still I couldn't figure out how to install it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8):

MusicTeX is deprecated and no longer maintained.  You probably mean MusixTeX.

I'm reasonably acquainted with TeX (to the degree that Donald Knuth considerably simplified an example in the "Dirty Tricks" appendix of the TeXbook according to my suggestions) and do not use it.

MusixTeX is not a way to represent music but rather for piecing together musical elements.  If you do your text processing by writing the PDF file yourself, you'll be happy writing MusixTeX input.  If you prefer doing your text processing by writing PostScript, MusixTeX will be a bit terse for your taste.

Take a look at LilyPond instead.  Similar workflow to LaTeX (namely batch processing from a text-based source), but higher level regarding the treatment of music.  Also it is helpful that it produces Midi files.

Answer (score 3):

For those still interested in `MusiXTeX`, you can find the package and installation instructions at [MusiXTeX CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/musixtex).

It's [documentation](https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/musixtex/doc/musixdoc.pdf) gives a good overview about typesetting with this package. You may also be interested in chapter 25 "Extension Library".

However, if you use Latex-distributions, like MikTex, you just code like below and, depending on the consols settings, load what's missing on-demand. This simplifies installation, at least to me.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{harmony}

% p.22 How to Play RB

\begin{document}

 \begin{music}
    \generalsignature{-2}
    \mulooseness=0
    \linegoal=1
    \nobarnumbers
    \parindent0pt\startpiece
    \Notes\qa f\en\bar
    \Notes\zcharnote{r}{\HH.B..$\flat$...}\qa{gigi}\en\bar
    \Notes\hl{.i}\qa f\en\bar
    \Notes\zcharnote{r}{\HH.E..$\flat$7...}\qa{gigi}\en\bar
    \Notes\hl{.i}\qa f\en
    \endpiece
 \end{music}
\end{document}
```